# C Insertion Sort Program Fails With Many Inputs

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Heyo!

I'm new to C and have hit a brick wall trying to sort a set of numbers.

If I input '5 3 0 9 5', it will correctly return 9 5 5 3 0.

However, '5 3 0 0 9 9 10 11 13 14 9' doesn't return a thing. Some debugging shows it gets to the 3, then just stops.

Where should I start looking?

Here's my code, but general suggestions are fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getvals(int A[]);
void val_swap(int *a,int *b);

int main() {
    int len = 0;
    int vals[len];

    len = getvals(vals);

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    /* Search through the values from start to finish */
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        /* Search back through the values, right to left. If we find a smaller value, swap. */
        for (j = i-1; j >= 0 && vals[j+1] > vals[j]; j--) {
            /* Swap */
            val_swap(&vals[j], &vals[j+1]);
        }
    }

    /* Print the sorted array */
    int k = 0;
    for (; k < len; k++) {
        printf("%d ", vals[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}

int getvals(int A[]) {
    /* Gets a list of integer values from the user */ 
    int num, arr_len = 0;
    printf("Enter numbers. CTRL + D to end: ");
    while(scanf("%d", &num)) {
        A[arr_len] = num;
        arr_len++;
    }
    return arr_len;
}

void val_swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp;
    /* Save the value of b to temp var */
    tmp = *b;
    /* Swap the pointer values */
    *b = *a;
    /* Reassign value */
    *a = tmp;
}
```

Comment: How much size do you expect to have in `vals[]` after `int len = 0;    int vals[len]; len = getvals(vals);` ?

Comment: where do you resize vals array? it’s zero length.

Comment: Do you know about using `malloc()` and `free()`, i.e. dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @YunnoschHoping that it will resize to arr_len?

Comment: Your `scanf` is also wrong, as it will allow continuation on an EOF condition (which `scanf` can return, and is *not* equivalent to zero, fyi.)

Comment: How do you expect the array to resize?  Just because the value of a variable is changed? Or fully automatically? Those are features of more complex containers than C provides. You have some background in other languages, don't you?

Comment: By the way, if you try to ping a user (e.g. @Yunnosch) you need to be careful with ending the name. YunnoschHoping is not an existing user... ;-) Only making fun of you in a hopefully helpful way.

Comment: @Yunnosch Oops! And thanks, I fixed it! (C arrays are weiiirddd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the returned value of getvals is less than the amount of '5 3 0 0 9 9 10 11 13 14 9' , so many data.

But I am wondering whether it can pass the compilation, int vals[len], when len is 0, we don't say whether this is right, but the size of vals has already fixxed because the space of vals is in stack, no heap's.

So in my opinion, there are no enough spaces to run the program.

Comment: This was correct. I was accessing memory location's I didn't have access to. vals[1000] works just fine!

Comment: Congratulations!